# Image blurs after assignment

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow

I just started learning Tensorflow and Numpy concepts. I am reshaping differently shaped images using Tensorflow to one fixed shape for which I am making use of loop. At the end of the loop, I am accumulating this reshaped images into one array. Now, if I plot the image from this array, I get blurred image. But if I plot the instance of reshaped image using Tensorflow, I get the correct image. Please can anybody explain me where I am going wrong in this?

**Code:**

```
fixedW = 227.0
fixedH = 227.0
X_data = np.zeros((3, fixedW, fixedH, 3), dtype = np.float32)  # Only 3 images in this example
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(3):
        img = matplotlib.image.imread(image_file_name[i])
        preshape = img.shape
        img = np.reshape(img, (1, preshape[0], preshape[1], preshape[2]))  #Make it single batched image
        tf_img = tf.image.resize_images(img, (fixedW, fixedH), tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
        resized_img = sess.run(tf_img)[0]
        print(resized_img.shape)  # Prints correctly
        X_data[i, :, :, :] = resized_img[:, :, :]  # Something is wrong here

# This plots correctly
plt.imshow(resized_img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Correct image]

```
# This plots some blurred image
plt.imshow(X_data[2])
plt.show()
```

[image: Blurred incorrect image]

Please can anybody explain me where I am going wrong in this and what concept am I missing here in my understanding of this assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. The problem was with X_data type. The function `imshow` takes values of type uint8 or float32 only and moreover the values have to be in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.

My variable X_data was accepting types of float32 but the values were greater than 1. So converting the type of X_data to uint8 solved the problem.

Here is the solution line:

```
X_data = np.zeros((3, fixedW, fixedH, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If converting the data to `uint8` solves the problem, the following might solve it aswell (without having to declare the array as `uint8`):

```
plt.imshow(X_data[2], vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

From your problem, I do understand that your float image is actually in the range of `[0, 255]` (which is what the conversion to uint ends up doing).

The real problem then seems to be that matplotlib's `imshow` automatically adjusts the `vmin` and `vmax` of the image to the `X_data[2].min()` and `X_data[2].max()` by default if they are not provided.

If you provide `vmin=0` and `vmax=255` the plotting should be identical (and maybe more adequate) to rounding your data to unsigned bytes.

However, it might not be the case, since the code cannot be replicated and thus, I cannot test it :P.